# How to add accounts to Jenkins without the web interface?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, command-line-interface

I want to automate the entire installation of Jenkins, given a list of user names I want to be able to create user accounts for each. The only method I've read to set up user accounts is here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup

Tried seeing if there was an option to configure with command line at:
             `https://localhost:8080/cli/`
But does not seem to the be case.

Is it possible to add user accounts without using the web interface? More specifically a method that is scriptable.

My last resort is to do raw post requests but hoping there is a nicer way.

Comment: If you have LDAP or AD, there is no need to individually add accounts, and permissions can be controlled through user groups, that are managed through the LDAP/AD

Comment: @Slav, how would you programmically go about setting this configuration? Are you aware of any configuration files you could have pre-configured and just drop in the installation?

Comment: All of Jenkins configs (and plugins) are XML files, so you could programmatically change them with script language (some changes won't take affect until restart/reload). Under `$JENKINS_HOME` there is a `config.xml` that is the main configuration, including the security/authentication. Have a look at it. As for the reload, the `jenkins cli` has a reload command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, it is possible to script provisioning for jenkins. But not with the cli tool alone.

I guess you want to use "Jenkins own user database" with Project Matrix Authorization Strategy.

**Steps to prepare provisioning:**

1. Configure your Jenkins manually (enable security, add rolls and at least one user)
2. Shutdown your jenkins (to let him write all in-memory changes to disk)
3. Copy $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml to your provisioning script (as as seed data)
4. Copy $JENKINS_HOME/users/ (as seed data)
5. Get the cli tool: `cd /tmp; wget -nv http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar`

If you do not want to have static seed data (one config.xml for each user) you can generate a (users/username/)config.xml using a bash script or a more advanced tool. But for simplicity sake you can take users/username1/config.xml as a template. Replace relevant data with a placeholder e.g. "PLACEHOLDER_FULLNAME" for full user name.

e.g.: 
change

```
"<fullName>sample full username</fullName>"
```

to

```
"<fullName>PLACEHOLDER_FULLNAME</fullName>"
```

In your provisioning script, iterate over all users. For each user, replace each  placeholder with the correct value.

e.g.

```
cp $SEED_DATA/templates/user/config.xml /tmp/config.xml
sed -e "s/\${PLACEHOLDER_USERNAME}/1/" -e "s/\${ChuckNorris}/dog/" /tmp/config.xml
sed -e "s/\${PLACEHOLDER_EMAIL}/1/" -e "s/\${he@findsyou.com}/dog/" /tmp/config.xml
...
mkdir -p $SEED_DATA/users/$USERNAME/
cp /tmp/config.xml $SEED_DATA/users/$USERNAME/config.xml
```

When you want to use generated users config.xml please generate for each user some permission settings in $JENKINS_HOME/config.xml:

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
   ...
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Create:username1</permission>
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Delete:username1</permission>
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Read:username1</permission>
   ...
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Create:username2</permission>
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Delete:username2</permission>
   <permission>hudson.model.View.Read:username2</permission>
   ...
</authorizationStrategy>
```

**Provisioning steps:**

1. Install jenkins as you did before & maybe dynamic config generator (see above)
2. `cp $SEED_DATA/config.xml $JENKINS_HOME/`
3. `cp -R $SEED_DATA/users/ $JENKINS_HOME/`
4. `chown -R "jenkins:jenkins" $JENKINS_HOME/users/` (maybe optional)
5. `cd /tmp; java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ reload-configuration`